# How to launch a PWA in development mode?

Tags: angular, proxy, progressive-web-apps

I'd like to know if it's possible to launch a PWA Angular project in development mode?

I need to do this because while I'm in development I hide behind a proxy to reach my back-end. This is impossible in production mode.

I need to launch in dev mode because the app would be running with the proxy.

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while using ng serve it is not possible to launch PWA mode because It does not support PWA.
but, you can see if your angular app is a PWA by building the app in production mode and then running with HTTP server

https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started#serving-with-http-server

Comment: Thanks http-server worked as expected, I only needed to set the --proxy argument and it worked like a charm